# In python, "request.args.get" returns what type of variable?

Tags: python, flask

Please bear with me as I am a beginner in python. I'm using a framework to change values of my drone's parameters. One of the command I would like to use is vehicle.parameters['INJECT_TO_GPS']=100. When I use

```
vehicle.parameters['GPS_TO_INJECT']=100
```

It works well and changes it to 100. Now I want to include this in a function (I'm using flask to get the value of a from a web page), so If I use:

```
def change_value():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0)
    vehicle.parameters['INJECT_TO_GPS']=a
```

It does not work, printing me:

> error: required argument is not a float

I also tried:

```
vehicle.parameters['INJECT_TO_GPS']=float(a)
```

But in this, it complains that it has to be a string...
What is wrong with it ? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `type(a)` will give you the actual type of `a`. You can insert a `print(type(a))` as first line of `change_value()` and check the output

Comment: Add a `print(a); print(type(a))` after the second line of your `change_value()` function and you'll get the answer.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: `vehicle.parameters` seems to refer to [this](http://python.dronekit.io/automodule.html#dronekit.Vehicle.parameters), which suggests that `parameters` is more then just a dict. [`GPS_INJECT_TO`](http://ardupilot.org/plane/docs/parameters.html#gps-inject-to-destination-for-gps-inject-data-mavlink-packets) seems to take float, `INJECT_TO_GPS` isn't defined anywhere. `request.args` won't contain anything but `str` arguments, but that actually doesn't seem relevant to your problem at all. So if anything, it should probably be `vehicle.parameters['GPS_TO_INJECT']=float(a)`

Answer (score 0):

To know the type You can use inbuilt function type or isinstance to test that it belongs to that class:
    print(type(a))
    print(isinstance(a , class_or_type_you_want_check))